# How to return the adverbial form of the word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering if there is a method in Ruby to turn a word such as `month` to `monthly`.

Similar to `pluralize(word)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is any built in method, but you could write a simple one yourself:

```
CONSONANTS = [ 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ]

def adverbize(word)
  if word[-2,2] == "ly"
     word
  elsif word.length <= 3 and word[-1] == "y"
    word + "ly"
  elsif word[-2,2] == "ll"
     word + "y"
  elsif CONSONANTS.include? word[-3] and word[-2,2] == "le"
     word.sub(/e$/, "y")
  elsif word[-1] == "y"
     word.chop + "ily"
  else
     word + "ly"
  end
end
```

Another way to do this, that will work every time (this is mostly a joke, but you can use it if you'd like)

```
def adverbize(word)
    "In a " + word + " fashion."
end
```

Comment: I was hoping for one built in so most of the rules would be taken care of. Grammar is not my forte ;).

Comment: Edited accordingly, @LarsHaugseth. Thanks!

Comment: And of course there are exceptions to the exception, like *shy* => *shyly*. Good luck!

Comment: Improved answer, doesn't fix the one-syllable adjective thing though. I'll look into it, though.

Comment: How about *due* => *duly* and *true* => *truly*? Note that *unique* => *uniquely*.

Comment: This is great. I'll look into more rules as well